# How to access "permissions" package in Apache Jena?

Tags: eclipse, jena, apache-jena

I consider migrating a project to Apache Jena but can't get my mind around Jena's architecture. In this example...

https://github.com/apache/jena/tree/master/jena-permissions/src/example/java/org/apache/jena/permissions/example

... we make use of the "permissions" package.

But when I try to imitate what they do in the example using Eclipse and importing the *.jar files from apache-jena-3.1.1 as dependencies, the package org.apache.jena.permissions seems to be missing or inaccessible. Other packages such as org.apache.jena.rdf.model are accessible.

How can I access this package? Thank you very much.

--
Okay, I found the package at Maven: https://jena.apache.org/download/maven.html
Is this the only way to get it, even if you do not use Maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jena/jena-permissions/3.1.0) is usually a better place to search for a Java package:

[image]

If you still want to include JARs by hand (the link above is highlighted), don't forget to manually resolve the JARs that `jena-permissions` depends on:

[image]

P.S. I side with @AndyS that learning a dependency management system is 100% worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I found the download link on my own. You need to go here to get the package: https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/jena/jena-permissions/

Comment: And on maven central: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jena/jena-permissions/ Investing time in learning some basic maven (gradle, other) dependency stuff is well worth it.